# How do i add dynamic values and append it in one field?

Tags: html, jquery

form, which is fetching service name in `<td>Name</td>` and jQuery below is appending `sub total` as `quantity` increases with respect to `price`.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.qty', function() {
  var quantity = $(this).val();
  var sub = $(this).parent().next().children();
  var price = $(this).parent().prev().children().val();
  var subTotal = parseInt(quantity) * parseInt(price);
  sub.val(subTotal);
});



var i = 1;
$(function() {
  $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function() {
    var div = $("<tr />");
    div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
    $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
  });
  $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    // GrandTotal();
  });
});


function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
  i++;

  return '<td><select class="form-control select2 select-service" style="width: 100%;" id="service-select' + i + '" required  name="product[]"><option value="">--Select Product--</option> <?php foreach($dbf->fetchOrder("service") as $services){?><option value="<?= $services['
  id '];?>"><?= $services['
  service '];?></option><?php }?></select></td>' +
    '<td><input class="form-control rate" name = "rate[]" type="text" placeholder="Rate" id="rate1' + i + '" required readonly/></td>' +
    '<td><input class="form-control qty" placeholder="Quantity" name = "qty[]" type="number" id="qty1' + i + '" /></td>' +
    '<td><input class="form-control sub-total" placeholder="Sub Total" name = "sub_total[]" type="text"  id="sub_total1' + i + '" readonly required/></td>' +


    '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i></button></td>'


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Sub Total</td>
      <td><button id="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Add more controls"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>&nbsp; Add&nbsp;</button></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="TextBoxContainer">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control select-service" style="width: 100%;" id="service-select" required name="service[]">
          <option value="">--Select Services--</option>
          <?php foreach($dbf->fetchOrder("service") as $services){?>
          <option value="<?= $services['id'];?>">
            <?= $services['service'];?>
          </option>
          <?php }?>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control rate" placeholder="Rate" readonly name="rate[]" id="rate1" required></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="1" class="form-control qty" placeholder="Quantity" name="qty[]" id="qty1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" min="1" class="form-control sub_total" placeholder="Sub Total" name="sub_total[]" readonly id="sub_total1"></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>

  </tfoot>
</table>
```

this is the multiple dynamic input field of the same form above, which is adding `Name`,`Price`,`Quantity`,`Sub Total` dynamic field as add button is clicked.

My goal is to add all the sub-total from the multiple dynamic field and display it inside a different field.

Comment: I have created snippet out of your code, please fix errors in it so we can have [mre] in order to help you.

Comment: Hi, you upvote & accept below answer if that works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `each` loop to iterate through all inputs i.e : `sub_total` then get value of input and add it to some variable on each iteration and finally append it to some element.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).on('change', '.qty', function() {
  var quantity = $(this).val();
  var sub = $(this).parent().next().children();
  var price = $(this).parent().prev().children().val()
  var subTotal = parseInt(quantity) * parseInt(price);
  sub.val(subTotal);
  calculate_total(); //call to calculate
});



var i = 1;
$(function() {
  $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function() {
    var div = $("<tr />");
    div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
    $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
  });
  $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    calculate_total(); //call to calculate
  });
});


function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
  i++;
  return '<td><select class="form-control select2 select-service" style="width: 100%;" id="service-select' + i + '" required  name="product[]"><option value="">--Select Product--</option></select></td>' + '<td><input class="form-control rate" value="10" name = "rate[]" type="text" placeholder="Rate" id="rate1' + i + '" required readonly/></td>' + '<td><input class="form-control qty" placeholder="Quantity" name = "qty[]" type="number" id="qty1' + i + '" /></td>' + '<td><input class="form-control sub_total" placeholder="Sub Total" name = "sub_total[]" type="text"  id="sub_total1' + i + '" readonly required/></td>' + '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign">x</i></button></td>'
}

function calculate_total() {
  var total = 0;
  //loop through all inputs(sub-total)
  $("input.sub_total").each(function() {
    //check if value is not null
    total += ($(this).val() != "") ? parseInt($(this).val()) : 0;
  })
  //add total 
  $("#total").text(total)

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Sub Total</td>
      <td><button id="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Add more controls"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>&nbsp; Add&nbsp;</button></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="TextBoxContainer">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control select-service" style="width: 100%;" id="service-select" required name="service[]">
          <option value="">--Select Services--</option>
          <option value="1">1 </option>
          <option value="2">2 </option>
          <option value="3">3 </option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control rate" placeholder="Rate" readonly name="rate[]" value="10" id="rate1" required></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="1" class="form-control qty" placeholder="Quantity" name="qty[]" id="qty1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" min="1" class="form-control sub_total" placeholder="Sub Total" name="sub_total[]" readonly id="sub_total1"></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign">x</i></button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Total : </th>
      <th id="total">0</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```